# Tkinter Python managing scrollbar inside the listbox in a canvas

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, scrollbar

I got the code below which contain a listbox inside a canvas, I'm trying to place the scrollbar only inside the listbox but what I've got is the scrollbar always set on the whole form. Can you pls help me to put the scrollbar inside the listbox only and not on the whole canvas.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.form = Tk()
    self.form.title("Admin");
    self.form.geometry('608x620+400+50')
    self.form.option_add("*font",("Monotype Corsiva",13))
    self.form.overrideredirect(True)
    self.form.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.form)
    self.canvas.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
    self.photo = PhotoImage(file='src/back3.gif')
    self.canvas.create_image(-7,-8,image=self.photo,anchor=NW)

    self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="vertical")
    self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.canvas, width=78, height=15,yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.lb.place(relx=0.04,rely=0.17)
    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.lb.yview)
    self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="none")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a `Frame` to wrap the `Listbox` and the `Scrollbar`. Here it is a class I wrote to do the same thing, it does not fit exactly with your code - I use `grid()` instead of `pack()` -, but you get the idea.

```
class ScrollableListbox(tk.Listbox):
    def __init__(self, master, *arg, **key):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        tk.Listbox.__init__(self, self.frame, yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set, *arg, **key)
        self.yscroll['command'] = self.yview

    def grid(self, *arg, **key):
        self.frame.grid(*arg, **key)
        tk.Listbox.grid(self, row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        self.yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
```